# Keep checkbox state across pagination vue-bootstrap

Tags: checkbox, vuejs2, pagination, state, bootstrap-vue

I am using a bootstrap table using pagination to display users. On every row a checkbox for selecting more than one at a time to perform an action.
I manage to write the functions to select one and select all, keeping the array across pagination.
But now I am not able to control the ui while navigating across pages using pagination. As I said, the array I created for storing the selected users stays across pages, but I 'loose the tick' on the checkboxes... It looks like the v-model binding gets lost while surfing the pages...
Here the inherent parts of the code, hoping someone could help.
In the template:

```html
<b-table
  v-if="users && users.length > 0 && !isLoading"
  id="table-transition-userList"
  :key="users.id"
  responsive
  :tbody-transition-props="transProps"
  :fields="fields"
  :items="users"
  hover
  class="mx-2 py-1 tbl-user-list"
  :per-page="perPage"
  :filter="filter"
  :filterIncludedFields="filterOn"
  @filtered="onFiltered"
> 
  <template
    v-slot:head(checkbox)="data"
  >
    <b-form-checkbox
      size="lg"
      v-model="isSelectedAll"
      @change="selectAll(data)"
    />
  </template>
  <template
     v-slot:cell(checkbox)="data"
  >
     <b-form-checkbox
        v-model="data.item.selected"
        @change="select(data.item)"
     />
  </template>
```

In the script data:

```js
fields: [
  { key: 'checkbox', label: ''},
  { key: 'fullName', label: 'Utente' },
  { key: 'user.username', label: 'Username' },
  { key: 'user.email', label: 'Email' },
  { key: 'buttons', label: 'Operazioni' }
],
totalRows: 1,
currentPage: 1,
perPage: 5,
pageOptions: [5, 10, 15, 20, 25],
filter: null,
filterOn: [],
users: [],
selectedUsers: [],
isSelectedAll: false
```

In the methods:

```js
selectAll() {
  this.isSelectedAll = !this.isSelectedAll
  this.users.forEach(user => user.selected = this.isSelectedAll)

  const notSelected = this.users.filter(user => !user.selected)
  const selected = this.users.filter(user => user.selected)

  // new selected users array without current page selected users
  let selectedUsersCopy = this.selectedUsers.slice().filter(user =>
    !notSelected.find(e => e.id === user.id)
  )
  if(notSelected.length > 0) {
    this.isSelectedAll = true
  }
  else {
    this.isSelectedAll = false
  }
  this.selectedUsers = [
    ...selectedUsersCopy,
    ...selected.filter(user => !selectedUsersCopy.find(e => e.id === user.id))
  ]
},
select(user) {
  user.selected = !user.selected
  this.isSelectedAll = false
  const selected = this.users.filter(user => user.selected)
  if(selected.length === this.users.length) {
    this.isSelectedAll = true
  }
  else {
    this.isSelectedAll = false
  }
  let isDouble = false
  if(this.selectedUsers.find(v => v.user.id === user.id)) isDouble = true
  if(user.selected) {
    if(isDouble) {
      console.log('double if user selected and isDouble', isDouble)
      console.log("object already exists", this.selectedUsers)
      return
    }
    else {
      this.selectedUsers.push(user)
      return this.selectedUsers
    }
  }
  else {
    const index = this.selectedUsers.indexOf(user);
    this.selectedUsers.splice(index, 1);
    console.log("removed, new array: ", this.selectedUsers)
  }
},
async pagination(page) {
  const payload = {
    limit: this.perPage,
    offset: (page - 1) * this.perPage
  }
  this.isLoading = true
  this.isSelectedAll = false
  await this.$store.dispatch('user/setUsers', payload)
  const response = this.$store.getters.users
  this.users = response.results
  this.isLoading = false
  this.currentPage = page
}
```

My pagination is calling one api with different limits and offsets.
I think the problem is to be found in the built-in checked property of the form checkbox though...

Thanks to anyone who could give me a hint.
xx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your store dispatch event doing an axios call to fetch the page of data? Then the row's checkbox state will be what ever is returned from the call to the remote server (in which case it is being reset).

Once you receive your paged data, you need to iterate over it and set the `selected` value to `true` or `false`, based on the existence in your `selectedUsers` array, before passing it to `<b-table>`

```js
async pagination(page) {
  const payload = {
    limit: this.perPage,
    offset: (page - 1) * this.perPage
  }
  this.isLoading = true
  this.isSelectedAll = false
  await this.$store.dispatch('user/setUsers', payload)
  const response = this.$store.getters.users
  // Restore the selected state before passing the array to b-table
  this.users = response.results.map(user => {
     // if the user is found in selectedUsers array, then set
     // set the selected state to `true`, otherwise `false`
     // to restore the selected state
     user.selected = !!this.selectedUsers.find(u => u.id === user.id)
     return user
  })
  this.isLoading = false
  this.currentPage = page
}
```

I believe you may have an error in this line as well:

```js
if (this.selectedUsers.find(v => v.user.id === user.id)) isDouble = true
```

I am thinking it should be:

```js
if (this.selectedUsers.find(u => u.id === user.id)) isDouble = true
```

Comment: Great! It works! I tried something like this yesterday but it didn't work, my code was slightly different...  Also, I found an error in the remove method, so I updated like this ```const index = this.selectedUsers.findIndex(u => u === user)
        this.selectedUsers.splice(index, 1)``` and it's now working fine. Thanks a lot Troy, really!